# Populating Listview with columnar data

Tags: c#, listview

Hi I followed the answers to populating the listview, but the list view is populated horizontally but rather i need it to be populated column wise
here's my code

```
listView1.Items.Clear();
listView1.Columns.Clear();

Dictionary<string, List<string>> Values = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
Values.Add("CODE", list_p_code);
Values.Add("NAME", list_p_name);
Values.Add("MRP", list_mrp);
Values.Add("ORDERS", list_order_qty);
Values.Add("PENDING", list_variance_qty);

foreach (string key in Values.Keys)
{
    listView1.Columns.Add(key, -2,HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    // Fill item
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(key);

    // Fill Sub Items
    List<string> list = Values[key];

    foreach (string data in list)
    {
        item.SubItems.Add(data.ToString());
    }

    // Add to the ListView
    listView1.Items.Add(item);

}
```

The output is as follows:

```
CODE 1 2
NAME x y
ORDERS 4 4
...
```

but I want it as

```
CODE NAME ORDERS ...
1    x    4
2    y    4
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Take a look at this, it may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297007/update-second-column-listview-from-textbox-changed-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand what are you trying to do. If you want:

```
CODE NAME ORDERS ...
1    x    4
2    y    4
```

Then it would be natural to think, that you have a set of items with these 3 fields, and each item-code has respective name & orders-count.

Now, your data-structure is designed absolutely incorrect! That is why you have problems!

Let's look at your code:

1. What if `list_p_code.Length` != `list_p_name.Length` ? How do you anticipate your **listView** to display that ?
2. You are adding columns dynamically in the same cycle that actually adds list items. That is new columns appear in each iteration. But how do you anticipate adding an item **before** all columns are initialised? Think about this.

Example with correct data-structes. Note, that you should init all colums before you start iterating over items.

```
public class YourItem
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string MRP { get; set; }
    public int OrdersCount { get; set; }
    public int PendingCount { get; set; }           
}

void YourHandler()
{
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    listView1.Columns.Clear();

    var items = new[] 
    {
        new YourItem { Code = "Code1", Name = "Name1", MRP = "MRP1", OrdersCount = 1, PendingCount = 1 },
        new YourItem { Code = "Code2", Name = "Name2", MRP = "MRP2", OrdersCount = 2, PendingCount = 2 },
        new YourItem { Code = "Code3", Name = "Name3", MRP = "MRP3", OrdersCount = 3, PendingCount = 3 },
    };

    listView1.Columns.Add("CODE", -2,HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    listView1.Columns.Add("NAME", -2,HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    listView1.Columns.Add("MRP", -2,HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    listView1.Columns.Add("ORDERS", -2,HorizontalAlignment.Left);
    listView1.Columns.Add("PENDING", -2,HorizontalAlignment.Left);

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        // Fill item
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(item.Code);
        item.SubItems.Add(item.Name);
        item.SubItems.Add(item.MRP);
        item.SubItems.Add(item.OrdersCount);
        item.SubItems.Add(item.PendingCount);

        // Add to the ListView
        listView1.Items.Add(item);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `CODE, NAME, ORDERS` as column headers, not part of the rows. Then add the `{1,x,4}` & `{2,y,4}` as the row data as you did before.

```
listview.Columns.Add()
```

Answer (score 0):

Example from MSDN: this is how you add (items and subitems, then the next item with its subitems):

```
// Create three items and three sets of subitems for each item.
ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("CODE",0);
item1.SubItems.Add("NAME");
item1.SubItems.Add("ORDERS");
ListViewItem item2 = new ListViewItem("1",1);
item2.SubItems.Add("x");
item2.SubItems.Add("4");
ListViewItem item3 = new ListViewItem("2",2);
item3.SubItems.Add("y");
item3.SubItems.Add("4");
```

Based on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.items.aspx